# Pattern for instantiating new instance of dependency upon injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies

Is there a pattern that will instantiate a dependency when it's injected?

Say you have a `Config` class that's being used differently by `Foo` `Bar` and `Qux`.

Instead of doing this:

```
$config = new Config;
new Foo($config);

$config = new Config;
new Bar($config);

$config = new Config;
new Qux($config);
```

Is there a pattern that can do something like this?

```
$config = new Config;

new Foo($config);
new Bar($config);
new Qux($config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a **dependency injection container** that can a provide "shared" instance (of your Config object).

Example:

```
composer require league/container
```

```php
<?php

// container.php

use League\Container\Container;
use League\Container\ReflectionContainer;
use App\Config;

$container = new Container();
$container->delegate(new ReflectionContainer());

$container->share(Config::class, static function () {
    return new Config();
});
```

Your classes should make use of **constructor dependency injection**.

Example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Domain;

use App\Config;

final class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

}
```